# uploadFile does not posts image to server file (PHP)

Tags: ionic-framework, file-upload, cordova-plugin-advanced-http

In my app I have the `cordova camera` plugin which allows me to take a picture and I can get the URI from it.

```
const options: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 100,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
};
this.camera.getPicture(options).then(
  imageURI => {

  },
  err => {

  }
);
```

I then use that URI to upload to my server.

```
this.http
    .uploadFile(
        'https://example.com/pages/attachments.php, {
            action: 'INSERT'
        }, {},
        'file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.ionic.starter/cache/1583144250046.jpg',
        'picture'
    )
    .then(
        fileResult => {
            console.log(fileResult);
        },
        err => {

        }
    );
```

But I am getting these errors from the `console.log` result:

> Undefined index: file in on line 1235
>
> Undefined index: file in on line 1236

These are the lines in `attachments.php`:

```
// The tmp_name is the name of the temporary file on the server.
$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
```

It seems like that `$_FILES` is empty but i'm not sure why. I assumed using `http.uploadFile` would send the file but i'm not sure why it isn't. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a problem related to your PHP code. Check [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) document, 
I think that `file` is wrong. Maybe you should try `picture` instead, because you used this name while uploading the file? But I'm not an PHP expert.

Answer (score 0):

According to your JS code you should use $_FILES['picture']

Are you using a PHP framework? I would advice you to do so in order to have your file upload handling more robust and more secure.